# BS4 webscraping Get text from several elements

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to extract several  elements from bs4 Find_all as text without success

been trying Get_text and for X in Y:

Tips please!

````
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL = "URLLINK"

r = requests.get(URL)

soup = bs(r.content)

data = soup.find_all('span', attrs= {"class": "XXX"})

print(data)```
````

Comment: Can you show us what is your script printing to console? Make sure that the `span` elements exists matching the provided class

Comment: ```soup = bs(r.content)
[<span class="sold-property-listing__subheading sold-property-listing--left">
        Slutpris 1 400 000 kr
</span>, <span class="sold-property-listing__subheading sold-property-listing--left">
        Slutpris 1 950 000 kr
</span>, <span class="sold-property-listing__subheading sold-property-listing--left">
        Slutpris 2 115 000 kr
</span>, <span class="sold-property-listing__subheading sold-property-listing--left">
        Slutpris 1 900 000 kr
]```

Comment: Also what is the expected result? Because the find_all method is indeed returning something

Comment: Want it to print "Slutpris 1 400 000 kr" for instance. Prefereably pick those out into a csv file or someting similar

Comment: print(data[0].text) print(data[1].text) seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

it better to use use CSS selector or `.select()` function

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<span class="sold-property-listing__subheading sold-property-listing--left">         Slutpris 1 400 000 kr </span>, <span class="sold-property-listing__subheading sold-property-listing--left">         Slutpris 1 950 000 kr </span>, <span class="sold-property-listing__subheading sold-property-listing--left">         Slutpris 2 115 000 kr </span>, <span class="sold-property-listing__subheading sold-property-listing--left">         Slutpris 1 900 000 kr</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
spans = soup.select('.sold-property-listing__subheading')

# or
# spans = soup.select('.sold-property-listing__subheading.sold-property-listing--left')

for s in spans:
  print(s.text)
```